# Can Kotlin coroutines be an alternative for Java's ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for scheduling long running background jobs?

Tags: java, kotlin, server, backend

The traditional java approach involves getting a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor by

`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`

And then running a bunch of `Runnable`s inside it using methods such as `scheduleAtFixedRate()`.

However, this approach locks you into Java's threading model, which can be challenging in a Kotlin codebase where you're judiciously using Kotlin's `suspend` and made your long running jobs (e.g: Network/DB ops) in a coroutine-friendly way.

You can always use `runBlocking{}` to forcefully run your suspend methods within the runnables to schedule them using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, but that hardly seems elegant. You're effectively going around the coroutine threading model and going back to Java's.

So, is there a way to run long running background operations with Kotlin's coroutines? Something with an API similar to `scheduleAtFixedRate`-like methods (e.g: Run X() at 5 PM every day - a Kotlin friendly replacement of cron jobs essentially.)

Comment: Discussions at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/coroutine-scheduling/12644, https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/coroutines-with-time-scheduling/2942 and https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1186 may be helpful for writing your own, but I don't know if there is a standard solution (even a third-party one).